# different distance between elements with same classes

Tags: html, css, sass

I've stuck with styling issues. What I'm trying to reach is make sure that every single h3 tag has same distance between bottom border of his container (pink border) and bottom border of his parent (picture bottom border). Now it looks like this:
[image]

Both of them has same css, difference is only with amount of text.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
<a href='{{link}}' style='background-image: url("{{image}}")' class="histories__image">
    <div class="histories__text">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="histories__underline"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.histories {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 &__image {
   height: 41vh;
   margin-top: 33px;
   display: block;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
   transition: filter 1s;
   &:hover{
     filter: brightness(80%);
   }
   &:hover .histories__text{
     bottom: 15px;
   }
   &:hover .histories__underline{
     opacity: 1;
     left: 0;
     width: 70%;
   }
 }
 &__text {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transition: bottom .3s;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid pink;
 }
 &__underline {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   bottom: 10%;
   width: 0%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: 15%;
   background-color: white;
   height: 1px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: width .3s, left .3s;
 }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Your problem is the translate(-50%,-50%). This will center you content vertically which you don't want in this case. Just use translateX(-50%)

Comment: Use bottom: 10px  in *px* instead of bottom: 10%;

Answer (score 0):

You can try using translate like this to center your content with the same class.

```css
.histories__text{
  width: 100%;
}

.histories__text h3{
  transform: translate(50%,50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6">
<a href='{{link}}' class="histories__image">
    <div class="histories__text">
      <h3>Your Text</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="histories__underline"></div>
</a>
</div>
```